# Benchmark an exe using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, benchmarking

I would like some guidance on whether i can accomplish the following using a bat file.
I have an EXE that can be run with 3 different variables, say A B and C
Depending on the configuration, the file is slower/faster (# of tasks completed/sec)
My idea was to create a batch file that would do the following

```
app.exe -a 5 -b 5 -c 5
log tasks/sec (app.exe outputs the metric)
run again
app.exe -a 5 -b 5 -c 10
etc... up to a certain point say 100 for each.
```

Can I do this without having access to the app.exe code?

If so, can you give me an idea of how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. `for /L` is your friend here.

Comment: simplest approach: `echo %time%` before and after the command and calculate the difference manually (if it's a one-time task)

Comment: The simple batch command would be (from the prompt) `>"logfilename" (for /L %a in (0,1,100) do for /L %b in (0,1,100) do for /L %c in (0,1,100) do "app.exe" -a%a -b%b -c%c)` - but remember the output will be produced 1,000,000 times, so `app.exe` would need to output a line such as  `time a b c` where `a`, `b` and `c` are the input parameters and time the time taken, all justified with leading spaces so that each column is a constant width. Sort the result, and you have your answer. All depends on the unknown - the output of `app.exe` (you'd need to double every `%` sign to run as a batch)

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses...I had figured out how to time my tasks so I must not have articulated my issue. The app.exe produces a measurement 100 tasks/sec or 125 task/sec, etc. I want to be able to read that metric and test various distributions of a/b/c to increase the metric rather than doing it manually...the app.exe simply runs indefinitely but runs faster or slower based on the 3 parameters. Hope that helps